# How to hide a DIV when reloading a page?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window, refresh, reload

I have a loading overlay that shows some information and I have a button to refresh the page. But I want the loading overlay only to appear once, not every time the button is clicked. (F5 doesn't matter). I was thinking of something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="reload();">

function reload() {
  if (window.location.reload()) {
     document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work... pls help

Comment: each time the page is reloaded (from the browser level, like f5), the JavaScript runs all over again - fresh.  The only way I could think to accomplish this is to track the page visit somewhere and use that as a determination (cookie, local storage, change the URL so reload is a different page ...)

Comment: alright, thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of client cookie, set a flag to client cookie if overlay already shown once, example code:

**Vanilla JS Version**

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

if (getCookie('OVERLAY_ALREADY_SHOWN')) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    // ... some conditions ...
    setCookie('OVERLAY_ALREADY_SHOWN', true, 14); // persist two weeks
}
</script>
```

**jQuery Cookie Version**

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
if ($.cookie('OVERLAY_ALREADY_SHOWN')) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    // ... some conditions ...
    $.cookie('OVERLAY_ALREADY_SHOWN', true, { expires: 14 }); // persist two weeks
}
</script>
```